# s3 bucket configuration changes takes effect only to new folders

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

Hi I am using AWS S3 buckets for storing images, I have changed the bucket policy, access permission, and CORS configuration for the bucket , but this effects only for the new folders which i have created after changing the configurations. The old folders will not affected by new configuration. whats wrong with this?

Comment: Can you possibly provide more information about what you are doing and what difficulty you are experiencing? For example, what are you trying to do and what is actually happening?

Comment: I have changed the cors configuration like this                           <AllowedOrigin>*</AllowedOrigin>
        <AllowedMethod>GET</AllowedMethod>
        <MaxAgeSeconds>3000</MaxAgeSeconds>
        <AllowedHeader>*</AllowedHeader> but this takes effect only to new folders not to existing folders

Comment: It might be a caching issue. Have you tried an old folder using a different browser or computer?